# Pass the type of struct to a function bound by a protocol

Tags: swift

I want to pass the type of my struct ("myStruct") to my function ("testFunc") which is bound by a protocol ("TestProtocol")

```
protocol TestProtocol {
    func getName() -> String
}

func testFunc <T: TestProtocol> (with type: T) {
    print ("testFunc")
}

struct myStruct: TestProtocol {
    var name: String
    func getName() -> String {
        return name
    }
}

testFunc(with: myStruct.self)
```

But I get the error that myStruct.Type does not conform to TestProtocol; yet it clearly does!

Comment: `myStruct.Type` (the metatype object of `myStruct`) does not conform to the protocol. *Instances* of `myStruct` conform to the protocol. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33112559/3141234

Comment: Also, structs (all types, actually) should be `UpperCamelCase` in Swift, and [don't write setters in Swift.](https://github.com/amomchilov/Blog/blob/master/Stop%20writing%20getters%20and%20setters%20in%20Swift.md)

Comment: One is a typo, the idea of writing getters or setters based on  random GitHub link? Thanks, but stay on topic for the question.

Comment: It's a common enough of issue in the thousands of questions I've seen that I found it worthwhile to spend my time and write it up nicely, rather than rewriting the same comments. I suggest you take a look, hopefully you'll find it quite insightful

Answer (score 0):

Your **testFunc** is expecting an instance of a class that conforms to **TestProtocol**. So just create one:

```swift
testFunc(with: myStruct(name: "John"))
```

To pass a type of your **myStruct**:

```swift
func testFunc <T: TestProtocol> (with type: T.Type) {
    print ("testFunc")
}

testFunc(with: myStruct.self)
```

Comment: I don't want to pass an instance, I want to pass a type.

Answer (score 0):

Use `T.Type` as the parameter type.

```
protocol TestProtocol {
    func getName() -> String
}

func testFunc <T: TestProtocol> (with type: T.Type) {
    print ("testFunc")
}

struct MyStruct: TestProtocol {
    var name: String
    func getName() -> String {
        return name
    }
}

testFunc(with: MyStruct.self)
```